# Adding webview through MainActivity

Tags: android, webview

If possible, how can I add a webview to my layout with only using code in my MainActivity.java class file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
*setting up webview* 
setContentView(webview);
```

or

```
ViewGroup yourLayout = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null); 
setContentView(yourLayout);

WebView webView = new WebView(this);
*setting up webview*    
yourLayout.addView(webView);
```